# Quickly applying gravity force between bodies

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, physics

I have a function for applying gravity forces between every possible pair of bodies on my game. It is the most used function, and can run more than 100k times per frame so every minor improvement on performance will make a HUGE difference here.

I replaced some divisions by multiplications and the general FPS increased from 5fps to 20fps with ~1000 bodies. This is how performance is affected by this function.

Precision can be decreased if it increases performance considerably. Just make sure you make it clear that a change will decrease precision in your review.

```
applyGravityBetween(bodyA, bodyB, collisionCallback) {
    var distX = bodyB.x - bodyA.x,
        distY = bodyB.y - bodyA.y,
        distSqr = distX * distX + distY * distY,
        forceA, forceB, dist;

    if (distSqr > (bodyA.radius + bodyB.radius) * (bodyA.radius + bodyB.radius)) {

        // ALERT: Radical actions were taken here to make faster code. Division was avoided at max.

        dist = 1 / Math.sqrt(distSqr); // Dividing one by the distance allows us to multiply instead of dividing later when setting actual velocities, which is more performant.
        forceA = bodyB.mass * dist * dist;
        forceB = bodyA.mass * dist * dist; // Instead of dividing by `distSqr` we can multiply by `dist` twice.

        bodyA.vx += forceA * distX * dist;
        bodyA.vy += forceA * distY * dist;

        bodyB.vx -= forceB * distX * dist;
        bodyB.vy -= forceB * distY * dist;
    } else if (typeof collisionCallback === "function" && bodyA.collidable && bodyB.collidable) collisionCallback(bodyA, bodyB);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a benchmark for each separate piece from this function, so you can focus on what you're going to improve:

`var` declarations took `3.199ms` on average to run. Collision check took `3.342ms`. `Math.sqrt()` took `3.122ms`.

This question is also related to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/stardust-2d-gravity-simulator-follow-up-1-the-planets) one, so if you're interested you can go there too and... Review.

Comment: `forceA = bodyB.mass * dist * dist * dist; bodyA.vx += forceA * distX;` looks even better.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Nailed it! How did I let that pass?

Comment: Maybe creating a `distCube` variable and multiplying by it is better than multiplying by `dist` 3 times twice?

Comment: You use (reciprocal) distance cubed twice (forceA and forceB). Just weigh overhead and profit. Let Force Be With You.

Comment: This is Javascript and everything is possible ;) `forceA = bodyB.mass * (dist = dist * dist * dist); forceB = bodyA.mass * dist;`

Comment: I wonder how long it takes to call `Math.pow(distSqr, -1.5)` (which gives the same result as your `dist * dist * dist`) compared to `Math.sqrt(distSqr)` plus one division and two multiplications.

Comment: @DavidK using `Math.sqrt` +  one division + two multiplications is faster, giving me between 20 and 30fps, while using the `Math.pow` method gives me ~15fps. Testing only in WebKit Nightly.

Comment: My first inclination was to try Fast Inverse Square Root, but [it probably won't help](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/30727/76831).

Comment: Maybe eliminate `distSqr` and just find `dist` instead: `dist = Math.sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY)` That way you can avoid a multiplication when you check for collisions: `dist > bodyA.radius + bodyB.radius`

Comment: Just to be sure: When you run this, I trust you've made sure it's only run once per unique pair of objects? I.e. it doesn't run on `(earth, moon)` _and_  `(moon, earth)`, does it? I assume you've done all that correctly, but just making sure

Comment: @Flambino Yeah, I'm 100% sure this runs only one time for each pair. No duplicate calls.

Comment: @JoshDawson but this way we'll be running the `sqrt` operation even when there's a collision, because we'll have to put it outside the `if`. I don't know if this change would increase or decrease performance, depending on the amount of collisions per frame.

Comment: How expensive is the calculation in the collision test compared to the rest of the function call? Actually quantifying the cost of each individual piece of the function would help show where the next optimization could occur. If this were a larger thing where the cost was mostly in subroutines, a profiler might help; as it is, a technique I've done is to isolate an individual line (or part of a line) and loop over it enough times so that having it in the loop or not makes a noticeable difference and I can estimate how much time it takes.

Comment: As an illustration of how _knowing_ the cost of each piece of code can help, if you find out that 80% of the running time is spent in `Math.sqrt` (and maybe a profiler would help on that particular matter), then the only hope for much better speed is to replace `Math.sqrt` with something less expensive, at least most of the time. That would be the next thing to concentrate efforts on, then.

Comment: @DavidK I'm going to benchmark every piece separately and post the results here as soon as I can. This entire application is also available on [github](https://github.com/tiagomarinho/stardust-2).

Comment: I've tried using Fast Inverse Square root function as well as a lookup array of precalculated inv. square roots. Not much difference experienced. May I suggest including a set of pre-determined positions for startup and then display an ave. fps at the end for consistent bench-marking. I would also suggest looking into a way to combine all bodies into one averaged mass/vector object then making a single calculation on each body.

Comment: **Benchmark results:** `var` declarations took `3.199ms` on average to run. Collision check took `3.342ms`. `sqrt` took `3.122ms`. Calculating forces `3.363ms`. Setting velocities `3.285ms`. Those results were consistent across many runs, I used a predetermined position for every body and each benchmark collected data for 40 seconds.

Comment: @Ross can you develop on how the implementation for averaged mass/vector object would work? Note that distance between bodies matter a lot when setting velocities so not every body is going in the exact same direction.

Comment: Instead of calculating each 2 body force separately the idea would be to calculate the sum average of all the forces interacting with body A (velocity, mass, position) and then calculate the 2 body problem once for body A. You could optimise by calculating the sum average for everything just once then for each body calculate the interaction against that average. -will see if I have time to code it up

Comment: Looks promising. Code would be really appreciated since I can't visualize how I could calculate that average once and apply it separately for each body since distance plays a role here.

Comment: Not sure if you know about this, but in the meantime see this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation#Calculation_optimizations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward note: To benchmark I simply commented out //self.addCollision(bodyA, bodyB); in step(). Referencing your github code.

To optimize just this method without looking at anything else we can do the 
following. This gives a physics workload at ~22ms compared with the original ~27ms on my system.

```
applyGravityBetween(bodyA, bodyB, collisionCallback) {

    var dx = bodyB.x - bodyA.x,
    dy = bodyB.y - bodyA.y,
    r  = (bodyA.radius + bodyB.radius);

    if ( ( ( dx > r || -dx > r ) || ( dy > r || -dy > r ) ) || ( dx * dx + dy * dy > r * r ) ) {

            r = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if( bodyB.mass == bodyA.mass ){

                r = bodyA.mass / (r * r * r);

                bodyA.vx += r * dx;
                bodyB.vx -= r * dx;

                bodyB.vy -= r * dy;
                bodyA.vy += r * dy; 

            }else{

                r = 1 / (r * r * r);

                bodyA.vx += bodyB.mass * r * dx;
                bodyB.vx -= bodyA.mass * r * dx;

                bodyB.vy -= bodyA.mass * r * dy;
                bodyA.vy += bodyB.mass * r * dy;    
            }

    } else if( typeof collisionCallback === "function") collisionCallback(bodyA, bodyB);

}
```

The above code improves by doing the following.

- simple bounding box collision check before using a more intensive distance check
- remove setting of variables as much as possible, i found in practice this is worth 2 or 3 multiplications in terms of cost. sometimes it's better to repeat the calculations.
- Use a comparison of the masses to speed up similar calculations - this is slightly faster where everything starts off with the same mass and could be useful for high N and similar mass simulations, otherwise I would take it out.

Areas for improvement;

1. This is not coded up but it is common in n-body simulations to group and approximate close,similar & far away masses by grouping them together as one. This can really help as N gets larger because it grows really fast.

**2. Reduce Callbacks.**

You only asked to optimise the gravity function so this is just an extra.. If you put the following directly into your step() method you can instantly double the speed of the simulation. I found a physics time of **8.8 ms** on average - Incorporating all improvements that's almost a third of the original time.

```
    var i1, i2, bodyA, bodyB, dx, dy, r;

    for (i1 = 0; i1 < this.dynamicBodies.length; ++i1) {
        bodyA = this.dynamicBodies[i1];

        for (i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < this.dynamicBodies.length; ++i2) {
            bodyB = this.dynamicBodies[i2];

            dx = bodyB.x - bodyA.x;
            dy = bodyB.y - bodyA.y;
            r  = (bodyA.radius + bodyB.radius);

            if ( ( ( dx > r || -dx > r ) || ( dy > r || -dy > r ) ) || ( dx * dx + dy * dy > r * r ) ) {

                    r = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);


                    if( bodyB.mass == bodyA.mass ){

                        bodyA.vx += (r = bodyA.mass / (r * r * r)) * dx;
                        bodyB.vx -= r * dx;

                        bodyB.vy -= r * dy;
                        bodyA.vy += r * dy; 

                    }else{

                        bodyA.vx += bodyB.mass * (r = 1 / (r * r * r)) * dx;
                        bodyB.vx -= bodyA.mass * r * dx;

                        bodyB.vy -= bodyA.mass * r * dy;
                        bodyA.vy += bodyB.mass * r * dy;    
                    }

            } else {
                //this.addCollision(bodyA, bodyB);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Reducing callbacks looks like the way to go. Also, I was optimizing this specific function because no one seems to answer my posts when I ask for an entire class review. I was probably going to ask for the PhysicsWorld class review later on.

Comment: Good work on every aspect of your review. I'm pretty happy with the performance now. :)

Comment: great, love the project! keep going!